# HTML Form Validation & Security

Tags: php, html

I have created a basic form with validation and php validation. I have also added a re-captcha to the form, because I was receiving a lot of inappropriate spam emails and for some reason after updating the security on the form the last time. I am still receiving inappropriate spam emails and due to this I am missing the important emails that may be getting sent to me via the form.

I have tried searching the internet and online tutorials, but their just telling me what I have already done. My code is as follow:

HTML:

```
<div class="contact">

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact US</h2>
        <div class="contact-form">

            <div class="col-md-8 contact-grid">
                <form id="test" action="form-process.php" method="POST">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='name';}" required>
                    <br>
                    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='email';}" required>
                    <br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown" onchange="handleOption(this)" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Crew/Gang</option>
                        <option value="NC Maphia">NC Maphia</option>
                        <option value="deadeye/index">Dead Eye</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown2" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Game</option>
                        <option value="Grand Theft Auto V">Grand Theft Auto V</option>
                        <option value="Red Dead Redemption II">Red Dead Redemption II</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown3" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Platform</option>
                        <option value="Xbox One">Xbox One</option>
                        <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown4" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Reason For Contacting Us</option>
                        <option value="Joining NC Maphia">Joining NC Maphia</option>
                        <option value="Recruitment Requirments">Recruitment Requirments</option>
                        <option value="Events">Events</option>
                        <option value="Report A Member">Report A Member</option>
                        <option value="Webmaster">Webmaster</option>
                        <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='subject';}">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="77" rows="6" placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'message';}" required></textarea>
                    <span class="msg-error error"></span>
                    <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ler9H8UAAAAAElg86pX58oN-G2a125GwNoBY9X4"></div>
                    <div class="send">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" >
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 contact-in">

                    <div class="address-more">
                    <h4>Address</h4>
                        <p>Maze Bank Tower,</p>
                        <p>Los Santos,</p>
                        <p>America </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-more">
                    <h4>Chat With Us</h4>
                        <p>PSN: Kyle-The-Gunman9</p>
                        <p>PSN: NC_Maphia</p>
                        <p>Email:<a href="mailto:email@example.com"> email[at]example.com</a></p>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleOption(elm) {
        if(elm.value == "deadeye/index") { // Check if Dead Eye was selected
            console.log("Dead Eye selected, redirecting");
            window.location = elm.value + ".html";
        }
    }
    $( '.send' ).click(function(){
        var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha' ),
        response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (response.length === 0) {
        $( '.msg-error').text( "Oops You forgot to do the ReCaptcha!" );
    if( !$captcha.hasClass( "error" ) ){
        $captcha.addClass( "error" );
    }
} else {
    $( '.msg-error' ).text('');
    $captcha.removeClass( "error" );
    alert( 'Processing...' );
}
})
    </script>
    <div class="map">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d37494223.23909492!2d103!3d55!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x453c569a896724fb%3A0x1409fdf86611f613!2sRussia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1415776049771"></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

My PHP code is on pastebin. You can view it below

https://pastebin.com/0ngFXM8U

I would like my contact form, so that when it does a full validate and users are unable to abuse the form. If that makes sense

Thanks in advance any any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use oauth of some kind instead of using re-captcha, in that case you will have mostly genuine users.

Comment: @Harshit would you be able to point me in the direction of a good working tutorial.

Comment: Many tutorials are available in youtube or websites. start with basics https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oauth2.0/

Comment: @Harshit Sorry for the late reply, but I have researched about it and this is to give permission to an app of some kind. I am also unable to find tutorials on this.

Comment: yes, you are partially right- oauth is a way of "login", best example is stackoverflow where when in login screen it asks us to either signin using google or facebook. this is oauth. So in your case if there is a login mechanism then you will know, emails from the form are coming from genuine users.

Comment: there are many examples on youtube, this one is simple for google plus https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-65R420rIUA